# Função para arredondar não funciona com scroll infinito

Tags: javascript

Usei seguinte função JavaScript para arredondar valores de desconto apresentados em minha loja:

```
function limparClasse(classe) {
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classe);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        var elemento = elementos[i];
        var string = elemento.innerHTML;
        var novaString = string.split('%');
        var arredondamento = parseInt(novaString[0], 10);
        var resultado = arredondamento + '%' + novaString[1];
        elemento.innerHTML = resultado;
    }
}


limparClasse('vtex-cpShow');
```

Ele funcionou, mas só nos produtos que foram carregados inicialmente.

Como meu site tem *scroll* infinito, quando rolamos o mouse e carrega os próximos produtos da página, o *script* não arredonda os valores dos produtos.

Como devo prosseguir para ajustar minha função de arredondamento e passar a chamar a função toda vez que carregar um produto e não toda vez que carregar uma página?

Comment: O certo é chamar essa função "toda vez" que carregar algum produto. Da forma que está, você chama a função uma única vez e ela "procura os elementos" no DOM e faz o arredondamento. Como os elementos são carregados conforme o scroll, você precisa chamar a função de novo. O mais certo é reestruturar sua função de modo que ela não precise percorrer todo o DOM quando carregar 1, ou 2 produtos... [Edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/358665/edit) e poste o código dos seus produtos e a função que os carrega para facilitar na resposta dos colegas...

Comment: Bom dia... eu não sei onde encontrar essas infos que você solicitou... infelizmente não entendo de JS e estou tentando resolver essa questão no esforço... consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- boa noite... editei a pergunta e inclui o código da página dos produtos e também a função do scroll infinito... agora pode me instruir como devo ajustar minha função de arredondamento?

Comment: "- *Segue função utilizada para scroll infinito.*" a sua "função" (este bloco de código) está incompleta; "-*Segue também o código da página de produtos.*" Onde, nesta página, está declarada a função que você postou para "arredondar"? Onde nesta página estão os elementos com a classe `vtex-cpShow` que você usa na chamada da função: `limparClasse('vtex-cpShow');`? **Não tem como reproduzir seu código dessa forma...**

Comment: Boa tarde @LipESprY-defolga- agora será que fiz da maneira correta?

Comment: Continua errado?! :/

Comment: Acontece que é muito código pra depurar e difícil de reproduzir. Não adianta vc encher a pergunta de código e achar que alguém vai perder um enorme tempo pra resolver o problema do seu código. Até porque dificilmente uma suposta resposta vai ajudar outros com o mesmo problema no futuro...

Comment: Desculpe amigo, é que realmente não conheço sobre o assunto e estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver... se for mas fácil para entender, segue exemplo na prática: artesintonia.com.br/esculturas/animais

Comment: Repare na sua pergunta. Imagine que seja você quem está do outro lado. São vários serviços: editar sua pergunta pra corrigir os erros de formatação; revisar todo seu código a fim de encontrar uma boa solução; voltar aqui e formular uma resposta com a solução. No meio desse caminho, editei sua pergunta e corrigi os erros de formatação. Até que me deparei com códigos incompletos. Aí, posteriormente, você voltou a editar a pergunta adicionando mais um caminhão de códigos. Aí tudo começa do zero... Leitura recomendada: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Entendo totalmente, por isso, peço desculpas pelo trabalho que lhe dei, não é mais necessário perder teu tempo comigo... vou continuar pesquisando "como chamar a função sempre que carregar um produto"... Agradeço por toda atenção.

Comment: Te enviei um e-mail, se puder dar uma olhada lá... estou precisando de alguém para executar 2 correções no meu site via js, remunerado... me responde lá... Obrigado!